# How should I use "as" in "From as a capable and brave soldier as you are, I didn't expect ... "

Tags: usage

> A-" No captain, I cannot leave the front. I stay and defend my country"
>   B-"Well done lieutenant! From as a capable and brave soldier as you are, I didn't expect otherwise"

A retired lieutenant wants to get to military action  because of duty and emergency he feels. His commander likes this and says he did not expect otherwise from a brave and responsible person like him. Did I use "as" correctly to convey this sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *as..as* comparison is not grammatically constructed, but there are three possible methods of correcting it:

- When *as* is used in a comparative with a noun phrase, the phrase's determiner ***a*** is moved immediately before the head, **after** any adjectives.

  > ... from as capable and brave ***a*** soldier as you are ...

  If you leave the determiner in its ordinary place, the construction *as a capable and brave soldier* is taken to be an ordinary preposition phrase with the approximate sense *in the role of a ... brave soldier*. That PP cannot stand as the object of the preposition *from*. (This is why user3169 finds the first *as* superfluous).
- Another solution is moving the *as* construction and its adjectives **after** the head:

  > ... from a soldier as capable and brave as you are ...

  This may seem a little unnatural to you, but it is actually much easier to parse: it sorts this complicated construction into its components, making it  clear that *a soldier* is the object of *from* and that the comparison involves the adjectives, not the soldier.
- The third possibility preserves your word sequence by replacing the first *as* with *such*:

  > ... from ***such*** a capable and brave soldier as you are ...

Comment: My personal preference would be for your second example but without "are" at the end. I don't think it's necessary in any of the three examples... not wrong, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "as" is correct, but the usage of "a" is not.

Instead of

- From as a capable and brave soldier as you are..

use

- From **as capable and brave a soldier** as you [are]....

(I strongly recommend leaving out the "are". It is not appropriate, because the "as" comparison is between "soldier" and "you".

Were it reversed, however, making the comparison between "you" and the attributes (capable and brave),  the "are" would be acceptable, but still not necessary.:

"From a soldier as capable and brave as you [are],..."